# C# Assigning numericUpDown value to a specific cell in Excel file

Tags: c#, excel, csv, numericupdown, gembox-spreadsheet

Heres what I have:

```
if (int.TryParse(kit_csv_quantity.Text, out int kitOut))
            {
                decimal kitOutValue = kitOut + kits_upDown.Value;
                kit_csv_quantity.Text = kitOutValue.ToString();
                ItemLine IL = new ItemLine();
                kitOutValue = IL.Quantity;
                allItems.Add(IL);
                
                SpreadsheetInfo.SetLicense("FREE-LIMITED-KEY");
                var workbook = ExcelFile.Load(@"C:\\Users\\carson.sumner\\Desktop\\PSP Kanban Program\\Backend Files\\Kits_be.csv", new CsvLoadOptions(CsvType.CommaDelimited));
                var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];
                var row = worksheet.Rows[worksheet.Rows.Count];
                var column = worksheet.Columns[worksheet.Columns.Count];

                var searchText = kit_csv_quantity.Text;
                var range = worksheet.Cells.GetSubrange("C2:C25");

                row.Cells[2].Value = searchText;

                workbook.Save("Output.csv", new CsvSaveOptions(CsvType.CommaDelimited));
```

What I have works to get the numericUpDownValue and add it into the Spreadsheet, but it just adds it into the bottom of the spreadsheet. What I want to be able to do is use the numericUpDownValue to edit a value in a pre-existing cell in the spreadsheet.

I am using gembox-spreadsheet to read the csv file into an excel workbook to edit the values, and then writes the excel worksheet back into a csv file.

Comment: The question is unclear! your code just gets the last row in `var row = worksheet.Rows[worksheet.Rows.Count];` and then replace the second cell of it with searchText in `row.Cells[2].Value = searchText;`! there is no other changes! please explain you question in more details

Comment: What cell are you targeting? Try using `worksheet.Cells["C2"].Value = searchText;` or maybe `range.Cells[0].Value = searchText;`.

Comment: sorry for not explaining more.  I am trying to target a cell in the column that is selected in my combobox. My combobox is populated by two rows in a csv file.  So when the user selects an item in the combobox. I want to get the value of that column, and then change the value of one of the cells in that column.